# One cron file per user

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have this requirement. I write a php application on which we can upload a wav file and schedule it to play it on some asterisk extension.
What I am doing is  like uploading a file and adding an entry in database for the filename, its location and schedule time. At the same time  adding a cron entry to a file.

For every uploaded file I create a separate cron file  because if I want to delete one cron entry from front-end it should delete the uploaded file, its related cronfile  and its entry in the database with a single  click.

My question is how can we use these cronfiles?
Can I move cron files this way  `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/user/cronfile1` `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/user/cronfile2`?

I tried it but getting error in cron log:

```
(cronfile1.txt) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question about cron-files, but I think a different method might be easier.

I would just add 1 cronfile that runs every x minutes that does

- check the database for any wav that needs to be played in the last x minutes
- fire a process that plays that wav

Now you need to save the "schedule time" to your database, and you're set. A delete does not need to change anything in the cronfile, because the cronfile just uses that database. This is the simplest solution, and the most clean.

If the smallest increment the user can set is every 30 minutes, the cron doesn't need to run more then once every 30 minutes, but if it is more precise then that you might need to run it more frequently.